# Cant Read .cpp file in c++

Tags: c++

(Sorry for my bad English) Hello, i tryed to read a .cpp file in c++ and... yeah, he dont read it good:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
std::cout << "FILEREADER 2000 \n" ;
FILE* file = fopen("C:/Users/michi/OneDrive/Desktop/Yeah.cpp", "rb");
char c;
char buffer[255];
c = fgetc(file);
int counter = 0;
while (c != EOF) {
    c = fgetc(file);
    fgets(buffer,255,file);
    puts(buffer);
}
fclose(file);
int x;
scanf("%d", x);
return 0;
}
//test
```

and the output:

```
FILEREADER 2000
nclude <iostream>

include <stdio.h>

nt main() {

std::cout << "FILEREADER 2000 \n" ;

FILE* file = fopen("C:/Users/michi/OneDrive/Desktop/Yeah.cpp", "rb");

char c;

char buffer[255];

c = fgetc(file);

int counter = 0;

while (c != EOF) {

        c = fgetc(file);

        fgets(buffer,255,file);

        puts(buffer);

}

fclose(file);

int x;

scanf("%d", x);

return 0;



/test
/test
```

so and you can see: `nclude`, `nt main`...

sorry for my bad english

Comment: You are reading 2 characters with 2 calls to `fgetc` before the `fgets` call? Why do you expect the 2 `fgetc`s to do nothing? You can read a file line by line with `while (fgets(buffer, 255, file)) { printf("%s", buffer);}`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```
c = fgetc(file);
int counter = 0;
while (c != EOF) {
    c = fgetc(file);
    fgets(buffer,255,file);
    puts(buffer);
}
```

The first fgetc reads the # in the first line. The one inside the loop reads the first character from each line. But you're not doing something with that character, which is why your puts is disappointing to you.

Note also that your fgets gets the entire line -- including the newline at the end. But puts puts the entire string -- including the newline -- PLUS a newline, which is why your output is double-spaced.